# ArrayAdapter(Filter) android

Tags: android, listview

Помогите разобраться с сортировкой/фильтром ArrayAdapter'a

У меня есть вот такой адаптер:

```
public class DrugAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<InfectionModel> im;

public DrugAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<InfectionModel> im) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.drug_list, im);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.im = im;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return im.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return im.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.drug_list, parent, false);
    }

    String title = im.get(position).getTitle();
    ImageView img;
    String liter = im.get(position).getTitle().substring(0, 1);
    //int color = new RandomColor().getMatColor("500");
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .textColor(Color.WHITE)
            .useFont(Typeface.DEFAULT)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .buildRound(liter, MaterialColorPalette.getRandomColor("100"));

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    return view;
}
```

Ну и сам InfectionModel:

```
private String id;
private String content;
private String title;
private String prew;
private String date;
private String url_img;

public InfectionModel() {
}

public InfectionModel(String id, String content, String title, String prew, String date, String url_img) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
    this.title = title;
    this.prew = prew;
    this.date = date;
    this.url_img = url_img;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPrew() {
    return prew;
}

public void setPrew(String prew) {
    this.prew = prew;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getUrl_img() {
    return url_img;
}

public void setUrl_img(String url_img) {
    this.url_img = url_img;
}
```

Как я понимаю, для него Filter  из коробки не подходит ибо при вызове

```
da.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
```

Увы ничего не происходит, подскажите, как можно переопределить метод getFilter дабы сортировка отрабатывала корректно? (Сортировка по полю title)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно при получении всех моделей (выборка из базы), в том месте где вы получаете `ArrayList<InfectionModel> im`, добавить сортировку при выборе из Базы Данных.

Если это ActiveAndroid, то код будет вот таким, примерно:

```
 return new Select()
.from(InfectionModel.class)
.where("_id >= 0")
.orderBy("Title DESC") //или ASC
.execute();
```

Если просто курсор, то примерно таким:

```
Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, rank, null, null, null, null, "Title DESC"); //или Title ASC
```

Comment: Это сортировка в ListView при вводе текста в EditText. Работа с БД у меня происходит в другой части приложения и никак не влияет на InfectionModel